# Can't allow port in docker ubuntu container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ufw

Want to allow a port say 4000. Ran:

```
root@66548e7316fc:/# sudo ufw allow 4000/tcp
WARN: initcaps
[Errno 2] iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)
root@66548e7316fc:/# 

root@66548e7316fc:/# sudo ufw status
ERROR: problem running iptables: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.


root@66548e7316fc:/# service ufw status
 * Firewall is not running...                                                                  [fail] 
root@66548e7316fc:/# sudo ufw reload
Firewall not enabled (skipping reload)
root@94d82c9ba002:/# sudo ufw enable
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
/lib/ufw/ufw-init: 118: /lib/ufw/ufw-init: modprobe: not found
/lib/ufw/ufw-init: 118: /lib/ufw/ufw-init: modprobe: not found
/lib/ufw/ufw-init: 118: /lib/ufw/ufw-init: modprobe: not found
iptables-restore v1.6.1: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.1: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.1: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.1: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.1: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.1: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 12
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.1: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 12
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.1: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.1: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.1: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians": Read-only file system

Problem loading ipv6 (skipping)
Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/after.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/user.rules'

root@94d82c9ba002:/# 
sudo ufw reload
Firewall not enabled (skipping reload)
```

I'm already root as you see `root@66548e7316fc:/#` in the above command prompt.

Comment: You can't usually change firewall settings inside a Docker container, and you don't usually configure the network from inside a container at all.  Is there a higher-level problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: actually i'm testing something inside docker container by hand (i mean trying manually)

Answer (score 4):

For allowing a machine to connect to a container's port you should use the `expose` or `ports` Docker's property.

> The EXPOSE instruction informs Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime. You can specify whether the port listens on TCP or UDP, and the default is TCP if the protocol is not specified.

from Docker's [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).

Or with `ports`:

> By default, when you create a container, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world. To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker containers which are not connected to the container’s network, use the --publish or -p flag.

from [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/).

Also you can specify an IP address on which this port will be listening:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:4000:4000 my container
```

Comment: That's the way to go. Running `ufw` inside a Docker container doesn't make sense IMHO, because you specify the allowed ports already in the process of starting the container.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to send some data from one container to another using `nc` (`netcat` cli). But the sender container says `connection refused`. So, I was trying firewall to allow the port using `ufw` cmd from the receiver site if that works. That's my scenario. Sorry for not specifying the whole story cause I thought that there was no need to specify this in the que description.